# How to load specific functions in php

Tags: php, html

I am building a website using php and i have used many functions through different pages.

I was thinking of collecting the functions to a single functions.php file and include it on the page i want to use the function but that would also include other functions which are useless on that page, so is there a way to include only the nessesary functions from the functions.php file instead of including them all?

Thanks,

Comment: answer to your exact question is no. but considering the speed involved loading a file with unneeded functions is not really an issue

Comment: so shall i collect all the functions and include the intire page? and i saw -2 on the question why is that i am new to this forum and i am not familier with the question types to ask?

Comment: for the latter click the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) button and read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have the Luxury to pick and choose the functions to load from a File. However, you may try putting all those Functions of yours into a `Trait`. Then use them within a Trivial Class wherein it would be imported. Here's an Example:

```
<?php       

        trait PreferredFunctions {

            public function doActionOne($param1){
                // CODE! CODE!! CODE!!!
                return null;
            }

            public function doActionTwo($param2){
                // CODE! CODE!! CODE!!!
                return null;

            }

            public function doActionThree($param3){
                // CODE! CODE!! CODE!!!
                return null;

            }
        }


        class Trivial{
            use PreferredFunctions;

            public function __construct() {
            }
        }

        $trivial    = new Trivial();

        $result1    = $trivial->doActionOne(1);
        $result2    = $trivial->doActionTwo(2);
        $result3    = $trivial->doActionThree(3);
```

Comment: The example is there: Just `require_once Trivial.php; require_once PreferredFunctions.php;`  Then on that Page, you can Instantiate the Class `Trivial`like so:  `$trivial = new Trival()`. And then you can call any function/method on the $trivial Object like: `$result1 = $trivial->doActionOne(1);`